# Asctec_Proc - Timeout: 0 bytes available 3 bytes requested

Tags: ros, pelican

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i try to run ros on the Asctec Pelican, but when i run

```
roslaunch asctec_proc asctec_driver_nodelets.launch
```

i get the following error:

> [ERROR] [1230811515.060357725]:     Read (-1): [ERROR] [1230811515.061434957]:   Read failed[ERROR] [1230811515.122562563]: Timeout: 0 bytes available 3 bytes requested[ERROR] [1230811515.123636163]:Error Reading Packet Header: Resource temporarily unavailable

On the Atomboard i have installed Ubuntu 11.10 and ROS-Fuerte.

The ros-node also sais it connects succsesfully  to /dev/ttyUSB0, Baudrate 57600.

I have tried it with extern current and with the battery.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem ?

Please tell me if further information is needed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67184/asctec_proc---timeout:-0-bytes-available-3-bytes-requested/) by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 336 on 2013-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

is the Atomboard connected properly to the low level processor of the pelican? This might help: http://asctec-users.986163.n3.nabble.com/how-set-serial-enable-for-the-LLP-tp4024434p4024443.html

---

Originally posted by [Markus Achtelik](https://answers.ros.org/users/867/markus-achtelik/) with karma: 390 on 2013-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2013-07-15**:
thanks...we was using a different cable, which of course do not work.
now all starts without any erros :)